# backbone-tastypie and backbone.offline

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage, tastypie

I have a tastypie API and now I'm playing around with backbone.js . To get both play together nicely I use [backbone-tastypie](https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie).

This works very well.

Now I want to add offline functionality by using [backbone.offline](https://github.com/Ask11/backbone.offline). This are my models and resources in backbone.js:

```
var Pizza = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/v1/pizza/',
});

var Topping = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/v1/topping/'
});

var PizzaCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Pizza,
    url: '/api/v1/pizza/',

    initialize: function() {
        this.storage = new Offline.Storage('pizza', this);
    }
});

var ToppingCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Topping,
    url: '/api/v1/topping/',

    initialize: function() {
        this.storage = new Offline.Storage('topping', this);
    }
});
```

Then if I create a collection and do a incremental sync on the stoage object, the request against the API loads normally, but I still have no models in the collection:

```
var pizzas = new PizzaCollection();
pizzas.storage.sync.incremental();
```

Can someone help me out here with knowledge about putting together backbone-tastypie and backbone.offline?